# Linq select based on IEnumerable property

Tags: c#, linq

I have the following:

```
IEnumerable<Corporations> Corps = ...

public class Corporation
{
    public string CompanyName { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Cars> Cars { get; set; }
}

public class Car
{
    public int CarID { get; set; }
    public string CarName { get; set; }
}
```

If I have the CarID = 4, how do I get CarName and Company name using linq.

I think I have come close with the .foreach (which is old school?) but get lost closing it:

```
var result = Corps.Where(cps => cps.Cars != null).ToList()
                .ForEach(x => x.Cars.ToList()
                    .ForEach(cr => cr.CarID == 5)
                        .Select (@y => new { FoundCorp = x.CompanyName, FoundCar = cr.CarName}....
```

Comment: What would you want to happen if there are multiple matches? What have you tried so far?

Comment: There couldn't/wouldn't be multiples or to be safe the first would be sufficient. I will be back in a min on what I have tried...

Comment: One other note, your class `Corporations` does not describe several, it describes a single `Corporation`.  Likewise with `Cars`.  (i.e. You should remove the name "s" from the end of both class names).

Comment: @Smudge202: this was a quick example of what I wanted to do but I understand and will edit the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 var check = Corporation.SelectMany(p => p.Cars.Where(m => m.CarID  == "4").Select(n => new
            {
                n.CarName,
                p.CompanyName
            }));
```

Answer (score 2):

The code below returns anonymous class instances, with property Cars containing car item matching conditon and Corps property for this car found.

```
var results = Corps
    .SelectMany(corp => corp.Cars, (corps, cars) => new { Corps = corps, Cars = cars })
    .Where(item => item.Cars.CarID == 4)
;

foreach (var item in results)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Car with id {0} have found in for company {1}", item.Cars.CarID, item.Corps.CompanyName);
}
```

You might want to replace this anonymous class with some particular that holds only CarName and CompanyName. Just replace the instantiation as below:

```
var results = Corps
    .SelectMany(corp => corp.Cars, (corps, cars) => new SomeResult(corps.CompanyName, cars.CarName))
    .Where(item => item.Cars.CarID == 4)
;
```

This code is safe to number of cars/companies found.

Comment: Why is this a better answer than Suraj's answer?

Comment: It isn't better. But then I've posted it there wasn't answer from Suraj yet.

Comment: This is a great answer but Suraj's fits my immediate needs.

Answer (score 0):

you want to find the corp where any car matches your CarId =>

```
int carid = 1;
var corp = Corps.FirstOrDefault(corp => corp.Cars.Any(car => car.CarID == carid));

if (Corp != null)
{
    Console.WriteLine(Corp.CompanyName);
    Console.WriteLine(Corp.Cars.First(car => car.CarID == carid).CarName);
}
```

As per Smudge's notes, you may consider using a HashTable or similar if you want to ensure your CarId's are unique.

Comment: I know this answers the question, but I've had so many issues with devs in the past not correctly accounting for multiple matches.  Don't suppose you could add some mention of that?  I personally push to enforce people to use `SingleOrDefault`, and carefully scrutinise anyone using First's.

Comment: in OP's comment -> `There couldn't/wouldn't be multiples or to be safe the first would be sufficient`.  It seems sufficient for his requirements

Comment: To be honest, I didn't notice the OP's comment.  Though, if there can't be multiples then it feels like `Single` > `First`.  Not convinced it would be considered _"Safe"_ but if that's what the op wants, then fair enough.